# bifactor model: factor loadings exceed 1

Tags: maximum-likelihood, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I fit a CFA model in `R` with the `lavaan` package using the "MLM" estimator, as the data follows a non-normal multivariate distribution. All items are scaled on a six-point scale.

```
fit_E <- lavaan::cfa(E_model, data = x, std.lv = FALSE, orthogonal = TRUE, estimator = "MLM")
summary(fit_E, fit.measures = TRUE, modindices = TRUE, standardized = T)
```

All factor loadings exceed 1 in the standardized solution. Did I do something wrong?

```
parameterEstimates(fit_E, standardized=T) %>% 
  filter(op == "=~") %>% 
  select('Latent Factor'=lhs, Indicator=rhs, B=est, SE=se, Z=z, 'p-value'=pvalue, Beta=std.all) %>% 
  kable(digits = 3, format="pandoc", caption="Factor Loadings")
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `lavaan` specifying `standardized=T` returns standardized loadings in a separate column in your output. The entire solution is not standardized and the first column still includes your unstandardized loadings, which will vary in magnitude as a function of the indicator variables' scales.

For standardized loadings look for `std.all` in your output, what you have stored as `Beta` in your table.